# How to stretch Container in ListView. Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I stretch vertically Container to the entire available Row space? Now the container is displayed only at the set height, the problem is that the height will depend on the transmitted text. I tried to wrap Container in Expand, but it led to an error (something like unbounded height) maybe because I use ListView.
Minimal expample:

```
  Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Column(
                  children: [
                    //some widgets
                    Container(
                      //height: 40,
                      width: 10,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                    child: Text(someText),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Now it looks like this
[image]

I want the blue container to be the full height of the text like here
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add shape to container decoration:

```
Container(
     decoration: BoxDecoration(
     border: Border(
     left: BorderSide(
     color: Colors.blue,
     width: 10,
    ),
   ),
  ),
  child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Text(
           'someText\nsadfghjgfd\nasdcudsufgd\nasgdngusd'),
  ),
),
```

Your Screen [image]

Comment: I'm sorry, I described the problem incorrectly. I need the text to be without highlighting, but to the left of the text there is a blue container with the full height of the text

Comment: Can you post the image what do you want

Comment: Please check my updated answer hope it solved your problem

Comment: i cant use card because i have some widgets in column(

Comment: Please check my updated answer using Container

Comment: Yeah, I also tried this, I think it will suit me, thanks)